# How to Manually Classify using SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, mathematics, implementation

Consider points x1 = (1,1), x2=(1,0), x3=(1,-1) from class **C1** and points x4 = (-1,1), x5=(-1-1) from class **C2**. Classify
the given data with SVM

[image]

How do we manually classify data by finding the equation of the line that will separate the classes?

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is your question? In your example, a simple decision rule like negative value of x axis splits the data into C1 and C2 class perfectly. Manual classification means finding such decision rules / boundary for such simple/cosmetic dataset.

Comment: @hssay Right I will edit the question I'm sorry, but to elaborate: I need to know how to find the equation of the line that will separate the classes.

Comment: I think that is a very broad question, having to explain entire process of SVM. I recommend reading some material on it or if you are not of the reading type try [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PwhiWxHK8o&t=93s)